# How to fetch browser cookie or browser catch in JavaScript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello Everyone i am new in JavaScript and jquery i am trying to fetch browser cookie and browser catche like we search some product on flip-kart or amazon and when we close this site and do normal work on net that time search product advertise show same like i tried.

so please suggest me what i can do for same.

Comment: That advertisement is coming via google or other web-advertisement company. so simply pay to them and they will do for you for showing advertisement on other website other then your own.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery isn't needed for cookie reading/manipulation, so don't use the original answer below.

Go to https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie instead, and use the library there that doesn't depend on jQuery.

Basic examples:

// Set a cookie
`Cookies.set('name', 'value');`

// Read the cookie
`Cookies.get('name') => // => 'value'`